# Выполнить команду командной строки на Java

Tags: java, процесс

Я запускаю программу при помощи командной строки следующим образом:

> Desktop\p.exe -Arg1

Как написать код запуска программы таким образом на Java? Я пробовал такие методы:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\p.exe\" –Arg1");
```

и

```
new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\p.exe", "–Arg1").start();
```

программа не получает аргумент "-Arg1". Она его получает, только если я вручную в командной строке запускаю программу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы уверены, что программа вообще запускается? Попробуйте использовать абсолютный путь до неё.

Этот код должен работать:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\...\Desktop\p.exe", "-Arg1");
Process process = builder.start();
```

Путь поправьте для себя на верный (не помню, в какую сторону и сколько слешей используется в путях на Windows).

Ещё вариант:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\p.exe", "-Arg1"});
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Я и так использую полный путь к программе. И этот код не работает. (Изменил вопрос)

Comment: Может ли данная проблема быть как-то связана с тем, что это Windows 10? Я уже поставил права администратора на Eclipse Java (среду программирования).

Comment: @nick а что за `p.exe`? Тоже ваша программа? Вы уверены что верно входные параметры обрабатываете?

Comment: нет, это не моя программа. Это официальная правильная программа одной крупной компании, с ней всё нормально. Почему с командной строки всё запускается ОК, а через Java-код нет?

Comment: @nick попробуйте свою программку запустить также, сами её напишите, чтобы она тупо выводила входные параметры. Я не знаю, честно говоря, в чём может быть причина, ибо с таким не сталкивался.

Comment: @nick обновил ответ.